# JavaFX binding a BooleanProperty to Paint

Tags: binding, javafx-8

I am writing a code that can take some boolean values from a part of some other code and change colours of certain circles on the screen accordingly. However I ran into problems trying to bind the boolean values to colours. I ended up with this:

```
unit1.getNeuron().getWorkingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (newValue == Boolean.FALSE) {
                controller.paint1 = new ObservableValueBase<Paint>() {

                    @Override
                    public Paint getValue() {
                        return Color.RED;
                    }
                };
            } else {
                controller.paint1 = new ObservableValueBase<Paint>() {

                    @Override
                    public Paint getValue() {
                        return Color.DODGERBLUE;
                    }
                };

            }
        }
    });
```

- but I'll have to repeat it for n times for n variables I use. Is there a different way to implement this?

Comment: use a binding that returns the color depending on the state of the boolean (vs. creating and setting a new Observable on change) BTW, there's rarely a need to extend ObservableXXBase - if you insist on manually changing the color in a listener, use a SimpleXXProperty<Paint> and _set_ its value

Answer (score 5):

Let' s say you want to create an `ObservableObjectValue<Paint>` you want to toggle based on an `ObservableBooleanValue`, then [`Bindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) is your friend:

```
final ObservableBooleanValue booleanCondition = unit1.getNeuron().getWorkingProperty();
final ObservableObjectValue<Paint> paintProperty = Bindings.when(booleanCondition).then(Color.RED).otherwise(Color.DODGERBLUE);
```

Comment: You really should explain your code. What's `unit1.getNeuron().getWorkingProperty()`? What does the code do. If you wouldn't put this piece of code in a question without explaining it neither should you in an answer.